# Custom Template with header and a line over the entire page

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, templates, report

I am trying to replicate a template on MS word using LaTeX. The template is as shown in the  picture below and must be applied to the entire document.

[image: Desired Template]

So far I succeeded to either have the text in the header using `fancyhdr` (but I failed to apply it to all pages, it is missing from the list of figures page and pages that include the chapter name) or to have the blue line on the left side (same problem as above) using `put \rule`. For some reason, I am not able to have them both at the same time and for all pages in the document.

I am including my preamble, hoping you can advise me on the way to tackle this issue.

```
% Preamble
\documentclass[12pt]{report}    
\makeatletter
\def\bstctlcite#1{\@bsphack
\@for\@citeb:=#1\do{%
\edef\@citeb{\expandafter\@firstofone\@citeb}%
\if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\citat
ion{\@citeb}}\fi}%
\@esphack}
\makeatother
% Packages
% ---
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{ulem}
\newcommand\semiHuge{\@setfontsize\semiHuge{23}{28}}
\def\blfootnote{\gdef\@thefnmark{}\@footnotetext}
\newcommand{\red}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\newcommand{\blue}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\newcommand{\green}[1]{\textcolor{green}{#1}}
\usepackage[top=2.54cm, includehead,headheight=45pt,bottom=2.54cm,left=2.54cm,right=2.54cm]{geometry}
\definecolor{lightblue}{RGB}{157,225,230}
\definecolor{purple}{RGB}{188,165,207}
\definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{146,154,200}
\newcommand{\lightblue}[1]{\textcolor{lightblue}{#1}}
\newcommand{\purple}[1]{\textcolor{purple}{#1}}
\newcommand{\darkblue}[1]{\textcolor{darkblue}{#1}}
\usepackage{amsmath} % Advanced math typesetting
\usepackage{hyperref} % Add a link to your document
\usepackage{graphicx} % Add pictures to your document
\usepackage{listings} % Source code formatting and highlighting
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[draft=true]{scrlayer}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%I dont want blck line in header 

\lhead{\textbf{\lightblue{\Large{Final Report}}\\ 
\purple{ECE 491: ECE Capstone Design Project -1\\
Fall 2017}}
}
\fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{CoE.jpg}}
%\DeclareNewPageStyleByLayers{titlestyle}{test}
%
%
%\DeclareNewLayer[
%  background,
%  innermargin,
%  width=1cm,
%  hoffset=1cm,
%  contents={\color{lightblue}\rule{\layerwidth}{\layerheight},\put(-30,650){\color{darkblue}\rule{.25in}{2in}} }
%]{test}
\doublespacing
%\pagestyle{titlestyle}  
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\title{Internship report}
\author{Rawan}
\date{\today}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\newpage
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\chapter{\large \textbf{Introduction}}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some pages in a LaTeX document have different pagestyles compared to the "normal" one. For instance `\chapter` typically uses `\thispagetsyle{plain}`.

You could try using the `memoir` class (a superset of `book`, `report` and `article` classes) which provides commands for setting the pagestyle for chapters, list of figures, etc. Along the lines of:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
 % your preamble
\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{your page style}
\aliaspagestyle{listoffigures}{your page style}
```

Untested. But read chapter Seven **Pagination and headers** in the documentation (`< texdoc memoir`) for more information.